# Convert GET variables from url to path using add_rewrite_rule in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting

In my wordpress website (nginx hosting) I have a product page with this url:

https://www.officeshop.co.il/product/my-product/

I have developed some functionality that allows to view different product models using get parameter:

https://www.officeshop.co.il/product/my-product/?build=product-572

I want to rewrite this url to make it SEO friendly to look like:

https://www.officeshop.co.il/product/my-product/build/product-572

I understand that the function add_rewrite_rule will do the job, but what parameters should I pass to it in my case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to your theme's function.php make your link SEO friendly.

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'change_product_links', 10, 2 );
function change_product_links( $link, $post) {
    if ( $post->post_type == 'tribe_events' && tribe_event_in_category('product') ) {
        $link = trailingslashit( home_url('/product/' . $post->post_name  ) );
    }
    return $link;
}
add_action( 'init', 'product_rewrite_rule', 5);
function product_rewrite_rule() {
        add_rewrite_rule( '^product/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?tribe_events=$matches[1]&post_type=tribe_events&name=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}
```